# Getting the same DNS TTL value for all websites

Tags: networking, dns, dig

I'm using the dig utility to get the TTL value of websites on local DNS and it always shows the same value of 5s for all websites. What can the reason be? How can I get the original DNS TTL value? Am I doing it correctly?

[image: The command I ran]

Also, running the command with the master/slave DNS server name of google gives 5m, while for some others I get no result at all.

[image: With Google's master DNS server]

I think in the case of 5s it's just a cached value and the 5m is the original value. But I don't understand why it's showing the same values for all websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *What is the reason for getting TTLs of 5s for all websites?*

Your local DNS server (possibly within your router) seems to be manipulating the DNS data, for unknown reasons.

- *How can I get the original TTL value?*

You sort of answered this yourself already: by using a good DNS server instead of a manipulative one.

- *Running the command with the master/slave DNS server name of google gives 5m, while for some others I get no result at all.*

A DNS server can operate in two roles:

- an *authoritative* DNS server will act as a complete & up-to-date source of information for one or more domains, and will ignore any requests that are not about those domains. There must be at least two public authoritative DNS servers for any publicly-accessible DNS domain. `ns1.google.com` is the usual name for Google's first public authoritative DNS server.
- a *resolving* DNS server will accept requests regarding any domain, and will make further requests to other DNS servers as necessary to figure out the answers. Usually, resolving DNS servers are for the owning organization's own use and/or their clients only, but there are a number of public DNS resolvers, like Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 or quad9.net's 9.9.9.9 and 149.112.112.112, or Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1.

These two DNS roles (*authoritative* and *resolving*) can be combined into a single DNS server that does both things, but the best current practice is to keep them separate whenever possible.

If you are getting your current DNS server configuration with DHCP, you could try overriding the DHCP-assigned DNS servers with one or two of above-mentioned public resolvers.

Or if your current DNS server IP address is the IP of your router, you might check the router's configuration to figure out what DNS servers the router itself uses, and then configure those to your system directly (to bypass the possibly poor/suspicious DNS implementation of the router). The router probably gets its DNS settings by DHCP or similar technology from your Internet Service Provider, and so uses your ISP's DNS servers by default.

You might also try just resetting your router. If this fixes the problem, your router might have had some DNS-affecting malware on it. Such router malware might be non-persistent, and just resetting the router might clear it (until it gets re-infected using the same vulnerability that allowed the original infection). If this is the case, you probably should see if your router's firmware can be updated to fix the vulnerability.